# Use field from custom metadata type as parameter in SOQL Query

Tags: soql, metadata

I have created a custom metadata type called 'Geolocation__mdt' with 2 custom fields: Distance__c and Limit__c

What I am (unsuccessfully) trying to achieve is to use the values stored in Distance__c and Limit__c as parameters for my SOQL query:

```
String queryString =
       'SELECT Id, Name,AD_JobAds_Anz__c,Vollst_ndiger_Name__c,ShippingStreet,LocateCity__longitude__s, LocateCity__latitude__s  ' +
       'FROM Account ' +
       'WHERE DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') <  3 and Kundenstatus_Direktvertrieb__c = \'Bestandskunde\' and Id != :theaccId ' +
       'ORDER BY DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') ' +
       'LIMIT 50';
```

But instead of:

```
WHERE DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') <  3
```

I want to use:

```
WHERE DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') <  Geolocation__mdt.Distance__c
```

and instead of :

```
'LIMIT 50';
```

I want to use

```
'LIMIT = Geolocation__mdt.Limit__c';
```

The main goal is to stay flexible since the values may change over the course of time and I don't want to touch my code every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some bindings:

```
Geolocation__mdt geolocation = [SELECT Distance__c, Limit__c FROM Geolocation__mdt WHERE ...];
Decimal maxDistance = geolocation.Distance__c;
Integer recordLimit = (Integer) geolocation.Limit__c;

String queryString =
   'SELECT Id, Name,AD_JobAds_Anz__c,Vollst_ndiger_Name__c,ShippingStreet,LocateCity__longitude__s, LocateCity__latitude__s  ' +
   'FROM Account ' +
   'WHERE DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') < :maxDistance and Kundenstatus_Direktvertrieb__c = \'Bestandskunde\' and Id != :theaccId ' +
   'ORDER BY DISTANCE(LocateCity__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'km\') ' +
   'LIMIT :recordLimit';
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your insides @Phil W and Nadine Thery. I knew it would be easy but sometimes one is stuck in thinking to complicated. Here is my final (functioning) code:

(There was a "_" missing in "FROM Geolocation_mdt")

Geolocation__mdt geolocation = [SELECT Distance__c, Limit__c FROM Geolocation__mdt];
         Decimal maxDistance = geolocation.Distance__c;
         Integer recordLimit = integer.valueOf(geolocation.Limit__c);

Answer (score 1):

Phil W. solution I think is the best approach. Just to give you some context, SOQL allows you to navigate between objects -as you wanted in your example- from the Query itself only when you have lookup (master-child) fields that connect them.

That's why Phil suggested making the first query to obtain the geolocation first. Only a gentle reminder that you watch your SOQL apex governor limitations and avoid putting queries in a for loop.

If this query is to be applied to several records at the time, maybe you need to rebuild the process from a bulk perspective.

Some documentation:

[Using Variables in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

[Relationship Queries in SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)